# Change this on live server without restarting the server @RequestParam(required = true)

Tags: java, spring, web-services

My team has uploaded a build with:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void registerUser(RequestParam(required = true))
```

I want to change it to `required = false`, without restarting the server. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you rebuild / restart the server. This would be much safer

Answer (score 0):

Made the changes in the desired class and compile in your local machine and then just copy the `.class` file only and paste it into your server's extracted folder of `war`. Suppose `MyProject.war` and it has extracted folder with MyProject Name and then restart your browser, not the server. Hope it may help you :)

Comment: .class file can view .. but there is no chance to modify and paste in the War. @Abhishek If you want to get the change you have to generate the war once change the required = false.

Comment: This might still restart the server depending on your server / configuration. Additionnaly, if the class has changed further this might provoke errors

Comment: I am agree with your comment @LaurentB.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri no need to paste or modify in the War. we can paste directly in the extracted folder of the particular war file. there is a provision to do like this, sometime we no need to put whole war and we have only few changes then we can directly go for this methos

Comment: Great Thought @KuldeePChoudharY. Continue.